# How do i add start and maxResults in @Query annotation using JPA repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to add start and maxResults in `@Query` annotation in JPA.
eg:

```
@Query(value = "Select * from agent_appointment where status in('CIN','CRTD') and start_time >= CURDATE()", nativeQuery = true)
List<AgentAppointment> getAppointmentAndCheckInList();
```

I want this query to return a specific number of results such as start and maxResults